# How to create SQL Nested ANDs inside of multiple ORs using LINQ

Tags: sql, linq-to-entities

I'm trying to create the equivelant LINQ query from the below SQL example:

```
SELECT *
FROM FOO
WHERE 
    ((a == <val1>) AND (b == <val2>) AND (c == <val3>))
OR
    ((a == <val4>) AND (b == <val5>) AND (c == <val6>))
```

There will always be an a, b, and c that will be AND'd together surrounded by an OR. This pattern can occur n amount of times.

The only solution I have found that work is using LINQ Union but the SQL generated isn't what I would like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try implementing the [`PredicateBuilder`](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) class.

Then perhaps you can use something like this:

```
var pred = PredicateBuilder.False<Foo>();

foreach(var criteria in myCriteriaSet)
{            
    pred = pred.Or(x => x.ID== criteria.ID && 
                        x.Name== criteria.Name &&
                        x.Created == criteria.SomeDate);
}

var matching = db.Foos.Where(pred);
```

This then assumes your criteria is enumerable. Modify as you need to accommodate your needs.

Comment: I needed to download LINQKit because I needed AsExpandable() because I'm using LINQ to Entities but it worked like a charm.

Comment: PredicateBuilder saved my day. Thanks @p.campbell for this straightforward solution. Actually this is why Stackoverflow is so famous among developer community :).

Answer (score 1):

You can make a long conditional statement:

```
var foo = from f in db.Foos.Where((f => f.A == val1 && f.b == val2 && f.c == val3) ||
                                  (f => f.A == val4 && f.b == val5 && f.c == val6))
```

Or, which is preferable IMO:

```
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<Foo>();
predicate = predicate.Or(f => f.A == val1 && f.A == val2 && f.A == val3);
predicate = predicate.Or(f => f.A == val4 && f.A == val5 && f.A == val6);
var foo = db.Foos.Where(predicate);
```

These can be conditional also:

```
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<Foo>();
predicate = predicate.Or(f => f.A == val1 && f.A == val2 && f.A == val3);
if (condition)
    predicate = predicate.Or(f => f.A == val4 && f.A == val5 && f.A == val6);
var foo = db.Foos.Where(predicate);
```